# slack how to know if bot recently posted

Tags: node.js, slack-api, botkit

I am using botkit, i have a bot that responses to a certain word.
But i don't want the bot to response if it recently did so.

Currently i am using `channels.history` method to retrieve 4 recent messages then find the bot id, if its there it won't reply. This is not pretty, i've been searching for useful methods to use but i can't find any. I just want to find out if the bot recently posted or not and do actions base on it.

```
   const targetBotID = 'GKALXJCM6'  
   bot.api.channels.history({
            channel: message.channel,
                latest: message.ts,
                count: 4,
                inclusive: 1,
            },  function(err, response) {
                  if(err) { bot.reply(message, 'Something is wrong with me, check log if there is??'); }

                  if(response){
                      const recentPostFound = response.messages.filter(function (member) {
                                                 return member.user === targetBotID;
                                              });

                      if(recentPostFound){
                        return bot.reply();
                      }
                        return bot.reply(answer) // Answer if no matching id found

                  }
              });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two solutions to your issue:

1. Record previous actions of your bot in some kind of app context (e.g. database). Then you can verify each time if your bot already answered.
2. Consider using [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api) instead of loading the chat history each time. Then your bot gets exactly one event request for each new message in a channel and you can be sure that your bot will only react once.

Comment: Someone told me to use a timer.. i tried it but it doesn't seems to go well so thanks for this.